# neo4j: If statement for deleting nodes based on relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to delete the nodes that has a relationship to each other node if the relationship exist. If the relationship doesnt exist delete the first node. Example:
I am using UNWIND because that is the data provided by the user.

```
UNWIND [{name:'John'}] as rows
IF EXISTS(u:Person)-[r:OWNS]->(c:Car), THEN
MATCH (u:Person)-[r:OWNS]->(c:Car)
WHERE u.user_name = rows.name
DETACH DELETE u,c
OTHERWISE
MATCH (u:Person)
WHERE u.user_name = rows.name
DETACH DELETE u
```

I tried using apoc.do.when however they dont allow EXISTS(u:User)-[r:OWNS]->(c:Car) as a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this without the APOC library and just use the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause.

```
UNWIND [{name:'John'}] as rows
// Match the person
MATCH (u:Person)
WHERE u.user_name = rows.name
// Check if she/he owns any car
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:OWNS]->(c:Car)
// Delete them all
DETACH DELETE u,c
```

I've checked and cypher has no problem if sometimes there will be null as variable `c`.

You can check this by doing:

```
DETACH DELETE null
```

It doesn't return any error, so I think it should work fine.

Comment: This worked for me and works well when you have a lot of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This query using [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) should work:

```
UNWIND [{name:'John'}] as rows
MATCH (u:Person)
WHERE u.user_name = rows.name
FOREACH(x IN [(u)-[:OWNS]->(c:Car)|c] | DETACH DELETE x)
DETACH DELETE u
```

Comment: I realized this isnt so useful when we have a lot of nodes (over ten thousand), the query becomes very costly. The solution provided by Tomaž Bratanič (below) is better.